# WPF Animation on ListBoxItem throws exception when clearing Item Source

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, exception, drag-and-drop

The project I am working on requires dragging items from a list box to drop targets in order to use said item from the list. The item is hidden while dragging (a `Bitmap` of element follows the mouse) and it collapses using a `DoubleAnimation` to 0 `Height` when placed. All this functionality works great the way I have implemented it using a `bool?` to determine visibility.

My project is multi-tabbed and because data needs to refresh between pages, the page clears collections and reloads them when visibility changes. My problem is that when I have collapsed items in the `ObservableCollection` that the custom `ListBox` control is bound to, I get an `InvalidOperationException` in `PresentationCore.dll` complaining: `'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' cannot use default destination value of 'NaN'`

Unfortunately this isn't helpful because I am animating `Height` using a style that specifies explicit `Height` values, and the `DoubleAnimation` specifies to animate to/from 0, so both values should not be `NaN`.

My best guess is that the actual problem is due to the `ListBox` applying a `DisconnectedItem` object as the `DataContext`. Maybe when the `DataTrigger` tries to access the `bool?` property that no longer exists because the `DataContext` has been changed, this is the result?

Whether this is the case or not, I have no idea how to get around this problem because it is happening out of my hands when WPF is doing animations on elements no longer in use.

I feel that leaving used items in the list but collapsed is a good way to do it, because I don't have to move items in and out of collections and it allows the animation to be nice and smooth. Also, in the code where I place from or return an item to the list from the target area, I have no access to the `ListBox` or it's collection, so it would make the code messier otherwise.

If anyone has tried something like this, has a better way of achieving the same UX or has a really good understanding of the underlying implementation that is causing this, I would really appreciate your input.

Cheers.

Update: The style XAML

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,7"/>
     <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="220"/>
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ContainerFill}"/>
     <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="OnMouseMove"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="False">
             <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                         <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                          To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="False"/>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                          To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="False"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                         <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                             From="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="False"/>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                          From="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="False"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="{x:Null}">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to animate height but getting error that height is NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230113/trying-to-animate-height-but-getting-error-that-height-is-nan)

Comment: Like I said, I am setting the height with explicit values in the style. I have added it to the question.

Comment: The point is: do not animate `Height`, create `LayoutTransform` or, preferably, `RenderTransform` and animate that.

Comment: I know it is possible to use scaleY to shrink the height, but that squashes it, rather than having it roll up. That is not the effect I want, because it looks bad. Besides, it works under normal circumstances, it's only when I clear the contents of the listbox that this exception happens.

Comment: *"only when I clear the contents of the listbox that this exception happens"* - that's a good hint. Use [`MultiDataTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) to additionally check for that. Btw, you may want to try to stop storyboards. Rather then running 2 different storyboards in enter/exit action create 2 set of triggers, where in EnterActions you start storyboard and in exit - stop it.

Comment: Thanks for you input, but if I just move the height value from the style into the animation it works fine. I didn't do this because I didn't want to explicitly define the height (it should be auto, but that causes a NaN exception), especially not in two places. I accepted that if it was in the style it's only 1 place to change, but It looks like I have to change 2 places. This seems like a WPF bug, not something I've done wrong. I guess the style is not accessible to the animation when it's removed from the visual tree? It doesn't complain about margin thickness though, so I don't know...